# Is imaplib safe to use for syncing Outlook office 365 emails?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib

All, just wanted to understand if Python imaplib is safe to use while working with emails. Im hard coding the email address and password in the script so just wanted to make sure it is OK to do that. If yes, how does it help to protect the security of user?

Comment: What does safe mean? _Im hard coding the email address and password in the script so just wanted to make sure it is OK to do that._ Is that related to the choice of library?

Comment: Correct. Choice of library. Im using imaplib library to get emails from Outlook server. I havent done this before so just want to make sure hard-coded email address and password is OK to be in the script. Or is there any other best practice that I need to follow. Does that help?

Comment: Also Im using IMAP4_SSL class to connect to server, if that helps!

Comment: Is your script available to anyone else?  Is it running on a public server?  Are you going to check it into source control?  Storing a password in plaintext is not imap specific, but depends on your environment.  At the least you should factor out the credentials into a configuration file.